# Vertical stack, middle section as tall as possible

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

Ok, so I have a very simple stack:

```
---------
|   A   |
---------
|   B   |
---------
|   C   |
---------
```

Both `A` and `C` have known and fixed heights. Yet the window height (a mobile viewport) is unknown. I'm trying to get `B` as tall as possible. I'm going to use `overflow-y: auto`, so overflowing is not an issue. The actual issue is expanding it to an unknow (but calculable) value.

I have solved this by calculating `$(window).height() - ($(A).height + $(C).height())`, but there must be a better way (or a jQuery plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the container has a non-`static` positioning, then make `B` `position: absolute;` and set both `top` and `bottom` to the heights of A and C, respectively.

For example, if `A` were 20 pixels tall and `C` 40, your CSS for `B` would look something like this:

```css
#b {
    bottom: 40px; /* Height of C */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px; /* Height of A */
}
```

Comment: @barraponto: Is that a problem? Full-height is generally how you make it take up the most space :)